# Copy from Visual mode to clipboard using Wayland

Tags: os-clipboard, wayland

This works well when I'm not using Wayland on Fedora 39 KDE:

```
nnoremap <C-c> "+
vnoremap <C-c> "+y
```

But this doesn't work anymore on Wayland.

What can I do to make it work?

My `vi --version`:

```
> vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Feb  8 2024 10:48:54)
Included patches: 1-80
Compiled by me
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             +xattr
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             +xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xim
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xpm
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        -xterm_save
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo yum install wl-clipboard` and [vim-wayland-clipboard](https://github.com/jasonccox/vim-wayland-clipboard) made it imediatelly work.